# date string column to timestamp column in a log file

Tags: logs, date, timestamps, filter

I have `log.txt` with sample output like these:

```
...
10-Feb-2022 15:15:14.099 lorem
10-Feb-2022 15:15:15.133 ipsum
10-Feb-2022 15:15:16.233 dolor
...
```

I expect the output of filtered log.txt will be

```
...
1644480914 lorem
1644480915 ipsum
1644480916 dolor
...
```

I have figured out how to convert date string to timestamp

```
date --date='10-Feb-2022 15:15:14.099' +"%s"
Output:
1644480914
```

My brain still don't get it how to apply that date command to log.txt.

Also How do I pipeline that date command?

```
printf "10-Feb-2022 15.15.17.012 water" | date --date=<what must i put here?> + "%s"
```

I expect the output of pipelined command is same, the different is without disturb other column, that is `1644480917 water`

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1521462/looping-through-the-content-of-a-file-in-bash then for each line read, split it into date, time and rest, convert and write back out.

Comment: So I need programming method instead of simple command or pipelining method, I think iterate lines of a log file is taking time.

Comment: Yup, it's about 6 lines of bash script. You have to read line by line.

Comment: Then, I need to know how to process certain column (date string) without disturb other column. Because iterate lines doesn't mean iterate column.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `date` command seems to allow for the `-d` option to convey a date/time. Try like

```
cut -d' ' -f-2 file | date +%s -f- | paste -d' ' - file | cut -d' ' -f1,4-
1644502514 lorem
1644502515 ipsum
1644502516 dolor
```

It `cut`s the date/time fields from the input, feeds them to the `date` command via the `-f` (read DATEFILE) option, `paste`s it back to the input file, and `cut`s out the old date/time fields.